# The method setTabListener is not applicable

Tags: android, android-support-library

I just finished adding the v7 support libary to my project and now I get these errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method setTabListener(ActionBar.TabListener) in the type ActionBar.Tab is not applicable for the arguments (ActionBar.TabListener)  TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.java  /LoginAndRegistration/src/com/example/loginandregistration  line 76 Java Problem
 The method setTabListener(ActionBar.TabListener) in the type ActionBar.Tab is not applicable for the arguments (ActionBar.TabListener) TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.java  /LoginAndRegistration/src/com/example/loginandregistration  line 80 Java Problem
The type new ActionBar.TabListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method ActionBar.TabListener.onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab, FragmentTransaction)   TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.java  /LoginAndRegistration/src/com/example/loginandregistration  line 52 Java Problem
The type new ActionBar.TabListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method ActionBar.TabListener.onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab, FragmentTransaction)   TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.java  /LoginAndRegistration/src/com/example/loginandregistration  line 52 Java Problem
The type new ActionBar.TabListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method ActionBar.TabListener.onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab, FragmentTransaction) TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.java  /LoginAndRegistration/src/com/example/loginandregistration  line 52 Java Problem
The method setTabListener(ActionBar.TabListener) in the type ActionBar.Tab is not applicable for the arguments (ActionBar.TabListener)  TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.java  /LoginAndRegistration/src/com/example/loginandregistration  line 72 Java Problem
```

Here is my TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.java:

```
package com.example.loginandregistration;

import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import com.example.loginandregistration.MyPageAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;

class TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

// Declare Variables
android.app.ActionBar ActionBar;
ViewPager mPager;
Tab tab;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from dashboard.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

    // Activate Navigation Mode Tabs
    ActionBar = getActionBar();
    ActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Locate ViewPager in dashboard.xml
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Capture ViewPager page swipes
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener ViewPagerListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            // Find the ViewPager Position
            ActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        } 
    };

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPagerListener);
    // Locate the adapter class called ViewPagerAdapter.java
    MyPageAdapter viewpageradapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Set the View Pager Adapter into ViewPager
    mPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);

    // Capture tab button clicks
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

         public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
             // Pass the position on tab click to ViewPager
             mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
         }

         public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }

         public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }

     };



    // Create first Tab
    tab = ActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(tabListener);
    ActionBar.addTab(tab);

    // Create second Tab
    tab = ActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(tabListener);
    ActionBar.addTab(tab);

    // Create third Tab
    tab = ActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(tabListener);
    ActionBar.addTab(tab);

}

}
```

I have no idea on how to fix the setTabListener errors but on the error:

```
The type new ActionBar.TabListener() ect.
```

When I add unimplemented methods, I notice that they are the same methods as my onTabSelected, onTabUnselected, onTabReselected methods.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the imports

```
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

with

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

There's a separate set off classes for the support library.

**EDIT**

You also need to replace

```
android.app.ActionBar ActionBar;
```

with

```
ActionBar ActionBar;
```

to use the support library action bar. Also, maybe it would be better to use lowercase `actionBar` for your variable name to make it different from the class name.

Comment: I now have the errors: "The method addTab(ActionBar.Tab) in the type ActionBar is not applicable for the arguments (ActionBar.Tab)" and "The method setTabListener(ActionBBar.TabListener) in the type ActionBar.Tab is not applicable for the arguments(ActionBar.TabListener)" when creating tabs at the bottom of the class.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry LAST error promise...
When I changed that, it fixed all my errors and gave me one new one (fun right?) that is that "ActionBar = getActionBar(); is undefined". So in order to make it use the support library (I just found this looking around online) I changed "=getActionBar()" to "= getSupportActionBar()" but now it gives me the error that that method is undefined. So how do I fix last error (hopefully)?

Comment: Change to `getSupportActionBar()`. All the method for support library are named in a similar way but have the word Support inside.

Comment: I changed it but it said that it was undefined

Comment: Change your activity to extend 'ActionBarActivity'. Make sure it's the one from support library.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for hanging in with me through this. (I know we aren't supposed to really say 'thanks' but you deserve it)

Comment: We're not supposed to say "you're welcome" but I'll say it :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are **implementing ActionBar.TabListener**. The this is referencing that implementation, not the fragment/activity itself.